# How do I find the surface area of a triangular prism whose bases are different dimensions?

Tags: calculus, area, surface-integrals

I am trying to determine the surface area of the main building of the famous Burj Al Arab in Dubai, but the shape of the building is quite awkward - as it was made to resemble a ship's sail. Both the top and bottom bases are triangular, however, the bottom base has much longer sides. Thus, there is a curve formed. My issue is, how do I approach to solve this? Is there a formula?

[Sketchup Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbIuo.png)
[Sketchup Model 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps71Q.png)

Height: 197.5m

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If the building is a triangular prism, then the sides are rectangular or triangular, and the surface area is simple to compute. But you also mention that the bottom is a curved form, so that would require some effort to compute. Based on your "surface integral" tag, I assume you have a knowledge of parametrized surfaces. If you can parametrize the curved base by a function $G(u, v),$ then the surface area is given by $\iint_U ||G_u \times G_v|| \, du \, dv,$ where $G_u$ and $G_v$ are the partial derivatives, $\times$ is cross product, and $U$ is the domain of $G.$

Comment: Both triangular bases are isosceles but the side opposite to the most acute angle (the one with no other pair) is a curve. This curve then goes downwards and expands to form the bottom triangular base with a greater perimeter. Does this make more sense? I attached an image for reference. If so, would that function still work?

Comment: I have two questions: (1.) does this picture give a view of the building from the front, i.e., the building standing up? I see some marks here that indicate height. (2.) Do you want to know the surface area, or do you want to know the area of this blade-shaped thing? Based on your "surface integral" tag, I expected that you would need to find the surface area of a three-dimensional object, but the diagram you provided is two-dimensional.

Comment: There is missing information. We need to know the side lengths of the sections as a function of height.

Comment: This shape is a section of a pyramid, so the formula for a pyramid could be used here.

Comment: I have added pictures to visualize. It is 3D, hence the calc tag, and I want to know the surface area. Not volume, or area. Just how much a person standing outside can see.

Comment: There are more images of the building here: https://faculty.arch.tamu.edu/media/cms_page_media/4433/BurjAlArab.pdf

It looks to me like the building is the intersection of a sphere with 3 half-spaces (or a 4th if you want to ignore the tower above he helipad).

Comment: Yea, or can also be seen as a sixteenth of an oval, with the top part cut out...